# How to find path to content in a different project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection

I'm trying to write a test that actually has to use an executable that sits in output directory of another project, I referenced that "other project" in my test, now what? How do you access a file in output directory of "other project" ? 
File has `BuildAction = Content` and `Copy to output directory = Copy Allways`

`System.Reflection.Assembly` methods aren't helping

Comment: Is the executable stored in your directory?  If so couldn't you launch a process to run `msiexec` with the other projects *Guid* to install?  I might be misunderstanding but I'm assuming your trying to install another application project onto the machine.

Comment: What do you mean by "I referenced that 'other project'"?  Assembly references do not have a BuildAction property.  If you add an assembly reference then the default "Copy Local" value ought to be true, and the executable should end up in your output directory.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to go to your "other" project's method you want to call and select "Create Unit Tests...".

Let it create the stub for you.  You should get a chunk of code like below and it should add the reference and create a Test References folder with an YourApplication.accessor file in it.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Your test
    ///</summary>
    [TestMethod()]
    [DeploymentItem("YourApplication.exe")]
    public void YourTest()
    {
        //your entry point that you want to call in the exe
        Program_Accessor.YourMethod();

        //Your assert test here
    }
```

Copy the DeploymentItem attribute to your test, wire up your method call, and try running the test.